# why phoenix liveview update/assign message make client contenteditable value revert?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

With Phoenix live view document I add a live page for writing a realtime form app. There is very simple demo:

```
<h2>Hello</h2>

Counter is222: <%= @counter %>
<hr>

<button phx-click="dec">-</button>
<button phx-click="inc">+</button>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th contenteditable="true">Month</th>
    <th>S1</th>
    <th>S2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">January</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">$100</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">$10220</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Server side code (just like document):

```
defmodule TicTacWeb.MemberSchedulerLive do
  use Phoenix.LiveView


  def render(assigns) do
    TicTacWeb.PageView.render("member_scheduler.html", assigns)
  end

  def mount(_, socket) do
    {:ok, assign(socket, %{counter: 100})}
  end

  def handle_event("inc", _, socket) do
    {:noreply, update(socket, :counter, fn(x) -> x + 1 end)}
  end

  def handle_event("dec", _, socket) do
    IO.puts("item")
    {:noreply, update(socket, :counter, fn(x) -> x - 1 end)}
  end

end
```

The problem is `<td contenteditable` value will be revert after I click `-` or `+` emit a message to server.

1. why `-` or `+` affect `<td>`'s value? Is't minimize change modified dom data?
2. Is there a best practice for such scene?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
After add contenteditable as data model, it was still not work, such as:
1. html snippet

```
    ....
    <td contenteditable="true">$100</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" phx-blur="somedata"><%=@somedata%></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2. backend

```
  ...
  def mount(_, socket) do
    {:ok, assign(socket, %{counter: 100, somedata: "$001"})}
  end
```

The `@somedata` also revert to $001 if click `-` or `+`.

Comment: Phoenix and LiveView creator Chris McCord discusses using `contenteditable` with LiveView at: https://elixirforum.com/t/phx-blur-with-contenteditable/25296/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why `-` or `+` affect `<td>`’s value?

It’s vice versa. They do not affect `<td>`’s value, on the contrary, it sends the *diff* between the previous state and the updated state and the frontend *applies* this *diff*.

`LiveView` has no idea about your local changes with the `contenteditable="true"` and hence it resets everything to its original state, save for `:counter` that gets updated. To support `contenteditable="true"` you need to make these `<td>`’s a part of data model so that `LiveView` is aware about the changes in there.

Comment: hi, as a freshman also has some wonder. why liveview manage frontend so strictly? Isn't be better performance and flexible if not revert client side custom changes. Such in the position which user edit some content maybe all edit will  be revert if server side push a message.

Comment: “Isn't be better [...]”—I am not the author of `LiveView`. Try to ask Chris McCord at https://elixirforum.com

Comment: Hi, I just test make td as data model, but it still doesn't work.I will update in the post later

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem by two step:

1. add `phx-update='ignore'` and the contenteditable will not be update!
   In this stage, it's `<td contenteditable="true" phx-update='ignore'>$10220</td>`
2. update phoenix_live_view to 0.4.1 which was `github: phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view`(locked commit is: 73e9a695eff1d7d21e4cb34ea9894835b3a2fa32) and the old version seems not support `phx-update`

Hope it also could be help you.

Thanks @Aleksei Matiushkin, I will dive into liveview diff algorithm.